# Plugin Development for Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-browser, android-ndk-r5

I am new to Android and using Android 2.3 .
 There is sample Browser plugin in the source code I am trying to build
 it but unable to do so.

To compile plugin [ In README.txt ]

1. run "make SampleBrowserPlugin" (compiles libsampleplugin.so and
   builds the apk)
2. the previous command produces an apk file so record its location.

   Using the above steps I am unable to build it.

   I have tried the following things :-
   I thought to build the code in JNI folder first so as to get the
   plugin  ".so"  so that after getting the ".so" would build the project
   apk using the eclipse .
   I tried building the code in the JNI folder using NDK build.The code
   was not geting build it was giving "undefined reference to
   JNIRegisterNativeMethod in JNIHelp.h "

   Can anyone tell me how to build the Sample plugin and install it
   on Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "make SampleBrowserPlugin" from the root of your source installation (on a Linux machine). That is, the same directory that contains "bionic", "build", "dalvik", etc. as child directories.